# When using ImageResizer as a pipeline, how do we protect our images

Tags: imageresizer

We sell photos in our web shop and it is crucial to our business that all images are kept private.

Images are on a different location and for this I have set up a site running imageresizer (windows server, IIS7) and images mounted as a virtual folder.

How do we best secure that images only are reachable from our webshops?

I read some about the remoteReaderPlugin, but images needs to be updated and as I understand it, remoteReaderPlugin is not on option since it perma caches?

Answer (score 0):

ImageResizer 4 has an Config.Current.Pipeline.AuthorizeImage event that you can handle and implement authorization logic based or resolution or any other parameters.

It also integrates with other ASP.NET and IIS authorization systems.

Comment: Thank you!
We ended up using AuthrizeImage event and signed urls.

Glanced at the code for remoteReader and it seems like it only signs the url and not the resizesettings. Leaving the possibility to get images by any size, just by changing the query. Don't know if it is intentional